# Access - how to add 2 columns and subtract 1

Tags: ms-access

I've uploaded a screenshot and the SQL query below as reference. What I am trying to achieve is finding out the profit/loss by adding up the field 'SubscriptionFee' and 'UNIFORM_UniformPrice' together and then subtract  'UNIFORM_SUPPLY_UniformPrice's total.

Pretty much [SubscriptionFee] + [UNIFORM_UniformPrice] - [UNIFORM_SUPPLY_UniformPrice]
is what I am trying to do but I can't figure out how to make it work.

When I try to run:

```
Sum([UNIFORM_UniformPrice]+[SubscriptionFee]-[UNIFORM_SUPPLY_UniformPrice]) AS Total
```

An error pops up saying:

> your query does not include the specified expression 'Subscriptionfee' as part of an
>   aggregate function

The apparent fix seems to be adding a "group by" but I have no idea how I type it out or if that is the fix for my issue.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT subscription.subscriptionfee, 
   uniform.uniformprice        AS UNIFORM_UniformPrice, 
   uniform_supply.uniformprice AS UNIFORM_SUPPLY_UniformPrice, 
   SUM([uniform_uniformprice] + [subscriptionfee] 
       - [uniform_supply_uniformprice]) 
                               AS Expr1 
FROM   (((uniform_supply 
      INNER JOIN staff_order 
              ON uniform_supply.[uniformsupplyid] = 
                 staff_order.[uniformsupplyid]) 
     INNER JOIN uniform 
             ON uniform_supply.[uniformsupplyid] = 
    uniform.[uniformsupplyid]) 
    INNER JOIN (subscription 
                INNER JOIN student_order 
                        ON subscription.[subscriptionno] = 
                           student_order.[subscriptionid]) 
            ON uniform.[uniformproductid] = 
   student_order.[uniformproductid]) 
   INNER JOIN invoice 
           ON student_order.[orderid] = invoice.[orderid];
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty common problem... Did you first checked for possible [existing answers to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=your+query+does+not+include+the+specified+expression+as+part+of+an+aggregate+function+%5Bms-access%5D).

Comment: Have you tried `subscription.subscriptionfee + uniform.uniformprice - uniform_supply.uniformprice As Expr1`?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use SUM in this case. You do not aggregate by for example using a group clause.

You can not reference an alias as UNIFORM_UniformPrice in the same select that it is defined in.

You statement should be like:

```
SELECT subscription.subscriptionfee, 
   uniform.uniformprice        AS UNIFORM_UniformPrice, 
   uniform_supply.uniformprice AS UNIFORM_SUPPLY_UniformPrice, 
   uniform.uniformprice + subscriptionfee 
       - uniform_supply.uniformprice 
                               AS Expr1 
FROM   (((uniform_supply 
      INNER JOIN staff_order 
              ON uniform_supply.[uniformsupplyid] = 
                 staff_order.[uniformsupplyid]) 
     INNER JOIN uniform 
             ON uniform_supply.[uniformsupplyid] = 
    uniform.[uniformsupplyid]) 
    INNER JOIN (subscription 
                INNER JOIN student_order 
                        ON subscription.[subscriptionno] = 
                           student_order.[subscriptionid]) 
            ON uniform.[uniformproductid] = 
   student_order.[uniformproductid]) 
   INNER JOIN invoice 
           ON student_order.[orderid] = invoice.[orderid];
```